# Semantic structure in HTML - Subtitles (Pre-HTML5)

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm new to HTML and want to make semantically correct HTML, however I'm finding it hard to work with what seems to be only headings, lists and paragraphs.

Particularly, I can't find a place that makes sense for subtitles. I'm writing a blog site so lets use that as an example:

A BLOG TITLE
the best blog in the world

post_title1
post_title2
post_title3

Semantically 'A BLOG TITLE' is h1. It makes sense to me that the post_titleX are h2, but it doesn't feel right for the subtitle - 'the best blog in the world' to be classed at the same level as them.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The specification has changed quite a bit since [the working draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/sections.html#the-header-element) that was up-to-date when this answer was first posted five years ago. As **@Andre Figueiredo** righly points out in the comments, [the published HTML5.2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#subheadings-subtitles-alternative-titles-and-taglines) is very clear on this specific use case (emphasis added):

> `h1`–`h6` elements **must not be used to markup subheadings, subtitles**, alternative titles and taglines unless intended to be the heading for a new section or subsection.

In short, use an appropriately classified `p` element inside a `header` element:

```
<header>
    <h1>A BLOG TITLE</h1>
    <p class="tagline">the best blog in the world</p>
</header>
```

---

In HTML5, there's an obvious solution:

```
<header>
    <h1>A BLOG TITLE</h1>
    <h2>the best blog in the world</h2>
</header>
```

When using HTML4 I personally tend to replace the `h2` with `p class="tagline"`, or something similar.

**Edit:** To motivate the use of `h2` in HTML5, think of the title of *Dr. Strangelove*:

```
<h1>Dr. Strangelove</h1>
<?>Or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb</?>
```

Does a `p` element make sense here? Not really — it's not a paragraph, it's a title. Does `h2` work as-is? No, we might confuse it with subtitles of the text itself. So what do we do? We use `h2` and group it with `h1` using a `header` element, thereby getting rid of the ambiguity concerning the subtitles in the text.

Comment: For HTML5, this does create a wrong outline. All the following content would be in scope of "the best blog in the world", which is typically not intended for a subtitle. You should enclose both headings in a [`hgroup` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-hgroup-element) instead.

Comment: hgroup has been dropped by the w3c

Comment: Use <p> tag as recommended by W3C for subtitles and style it using CSS. Read more here: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/common-idioms.html#common-idioms - and as @jscheel said, the hgroup has been dropped from the specification according to http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-admin/2013Apr/0003.html

Comment: ["h1–h6 elements **must not** be used to markup subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines unless intended to be the heading for a new section or subsection."](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-idioms.html)

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo: Updated the answer to reflect the changes to the HTML5 standard after the 2010 working draft the original answer was based on.

Comment: Someone in W3C clearly got too busy thinking, that forgot people use a CMS and 1. Do not use classes. 2. They *do* use H1-H6 - And yes, they *do* accent subtitles within a single section / article using `H2-H6` and the "suggestion" does not accounts often for practical use / solution.

Answer (score 8):

I would just use a paragraph element, it doesn't feel as odd to me as using a heading element:

```
<p class="subtitle">the best blog in the world</p>
```

[You's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910419/semantic-structure-in-html-subtitles/3910470#3910470) ("your answer", "his answer"?) would certainly be the way to go if you're marking up using HTML5.

Comment: Hmm. That does make more sense than headings.

Comment: I agree - since the subtitle is more of a description than any kind of title. If you think of it that way, the `p` tag makes perfect sense.

Comment: But the subtitle is (as its name implies) a title, and *should* therefore be a `h2` element. In HTML4, where we can't associate (or couple) `hX` elements like we can in HTML5, we have to resort to this slightly less semantic solution.

Comment: Right. I guess the definition of a 'paragraph' is a bit restricting. More like content?

Answer (score 3):

There may be a `SUBLINE` or `SUBHEAD` element coming soon that will be most appropriate:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/html5-hgroup-is-dead-what-you-need-to-know/

Until it becomes available we are left with trying to make `H2`'s (or some other H*x* element) or `P`'s or `Q`'s act as sublines/subheads/subtitles, etc. When it becomes available the structure of the content suggested in the original post will, I believe, be as follows (let's assume the `SUBHEAD` element is what it ends up being):

```
<h1>A BLOG TITLE
<subhead>the best blog in the world</subhead>
</h1>

<h2>post_title1</h2>
<h2>post_title2</h2>
<h2>post_title3</h2>
```

Although I would prefer it to be:

```
<h1>A BLOG TITLE</h1>
<subhead>the best blog in the world</subhead>

<h2>post_title1</h2>
<h2>post_title2</h2>
<h2>post_title3</h2>
```

The mere fact that a particular `SUBHEAD` element follows a particular H*x* element in my mind would semantically pair those two elements together, just as an `H2` (as a subsequent sibling, rather than as a child or other such descendant) following an `H1` associates those two elements.

In a world where the vast majority of web developers are clamoring to be allowed to make every single H*x* element on their page be an `H1` the OP here gets some credit for being concerned with proper heading structure and even going beyond that and recognizing that subtitles are not the same as headers.

Since I can't show rendered code here the Codepen at http://codepen.io/WebDevCA/pen/wzyIH shows a test of the `SUBHEAD` element and shows that, in my mind, the preferred positioning of it in the DOM is as an immediately subsequent sibling selector to its associated H*x* element rather than as a child element inside the H*x* element.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd use a heading for the subtitle, a wrong document outline would be created.

```
<body>
 <h1>John's blog</h1>
 <h2 class="tagline">the best blog in the world</h2>
 <div>…</div>
</body>
```

Here all following content (until a next `h1`/`h2`, if any) would be in the scope of the tagline instead of the actual blog title. Which is *not* what we want for a subtitle.

#### in HTML5

(**UPDATE**: The `hgroup` element got removed from HTML5. See my answer to another question about [how to mark up subheadings in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22451639/1591669) now.)

For HTML5, there is a new element especially for this use case: [`hgroup`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-hgroup-element)

> The element is used to group a set of `h1`–`h6` elements when the heading has multiple levels, such as subheadings, alternative titles, or taglines.

By using `hgroup`, only *one* of the child headings counts for the document outline.

```
<body>
 <hgroup>
   <h1>John's blog</h1>
   <h2 class="tagline">the best blog in the world</h2>
 </hgroup>
 <div>…</div>
</body>
```

#### in HTML 4.01

There would be two ways

1) Include the subtitle in the main heading, probably separated by a colon.

```
<body>
 <h1>John's blog: <span class="tagline">the best blog in the world</span></h1>
 <div>…</div>
</body>
```

2) Use a `p` (or if it's not a paragraph, `div`) for the subtitle:

```
<body>
 <h1>John's blog</h1>
 <p class="tagline">the best blog in the world</p>
 <div>…</div>
</body>
```

(if the immediately following content would consist of paragraphs, too, you could think of using the `hr` element after the tagline)

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution should answer the following question: "What would make sense to a screen reader?"

```
<h1>A BLOG TITLE</h1>
<p><q>the best blog in the world</q></p>
```

Comment: This use of `q` would only be correct if the subtitle is in fact a quote from another source.