# Correct markup for headers

Tags: html, semantics, markup

How do I semanticly markup the headers in the article as presented in the picture below? I often run into this problem; where I have a header that is visually first, but is a subheading, intro header or less important then the main header. I could put it after the main header and move it above with CSS, but that isn't always a ideal solution.

Another question: is there any special way to markup lead paragraphs?

[image: headermarkup]
**Not allowed?**

```
<article>
<h2>New prodcut</h2>
<h1>Launching our new x-series</h1>
<p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
<p>Integer varius, turpis sit amet accumsan...</p>
...
</article>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don’t use a heading element (`h1`-`h6`) for the subheading. This was once possible with the `hgroup` element, but it got removed.

Now the HTML5 spec has a section about [Subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/common-idioms.html#sub-head). Use a `p` element for the subheading, and group both, the heading and the subheading in a `header` element:

```html
<article>
  <header>
    <p>New product</p>
    <h1>Launching our new X-series</h1>
  </header>
</article>
```

If you think the lead paragraph should also be [part of the header (instead of the main content)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22387534/1591669), you can put it in the `header`, too.

Comment: Perfect. Just what I was looking for :)

Comment: The `<hgroup>` element very much exists and is recommended for this scenario: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-hgroup-element

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Standard as of 2023 recommends the use of the `<hgroup>` element for subheading, alternative titles, and taglines:

```
<article>
  <hgroup>
    <p>New product</p>
    <h1>Launching our new x-series</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  </hgroup>
  <p>Integer varius, turpis sit amet accumsan...</p>
  ...
</article>
```

**Permitted content:**

1. Zero or more `<p>` elements,
2. followed by one `<h1>` , `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<h4>`, `<h5>`, or `<h6>` element,
3. followed by zero or more `<p>` elements.

See: [4.3.7 The `hgroup` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-hgroup-element)

While not explicitly mentioned, I would consider the lead paragraph to be content related to a heading and would thus place it in the `<hgroup>` as well.

Setting classes like `<p class="lead">` is not required thanks to the `<hgroup>` element, which lets you target the subheading and the lead paragraph in CSS easily:

```css
hgroup > p:first-child { /* or  hgroup p:has(+ h1)  for the <p> before <h1> */
  font-size: 16pt;
}

hgroup h1 + p {
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

While what you are doing is syntactically allowed, I think it will case confusion for low vision users.

How about doing something like this:

```
<div class="newproduct>New Product</div>
<div class="articletitle">Launching our new x-series</div>
Lorem ipsum....
```

If you want to use some newer HTML, I would recommend you look into `article` and `section` tags.

Comment: It isn't very SEO friendly to not use h1, and by using article (as I am) a h1 should be present

Comment: Was your question about semantics or SEO? And you can use heading tags within articles. Each article should be about a stand alone "something" (i.e., news article, blog entry, dictionary entry, etc.). My response was specifically about people with low vision (blind or nearly blind).

Comment: My question is about semantics, and therefore directly related to SEO. But mainly about how to markup the headings with h1, and h2 if needed. I will update my question to be more precise

Comment: I tested against several validation tools (online only). None of them complained about invalid markup using your code.