# Is an HTML5 <header> tag unnecessary if there is only a single <hx> tag inside it?

Tags: html, semantics, semantic-web, semantic-markup

I've searched and have not come up with any useful answers, so here goes:

Is an HTML5 `<header>` tag unnecessary if there is only a single `<hx>` tag inside it? For instance, I have the following HTML5 markup:

```
<article>

   <header>
      <h1>Heading Title</h1>
   </header>

   ...

</article>
```

From an HTML5 semantics point of view, when there is only one `<hx>` tag inside the `<header>` and nothing else, is the `<header>` tag unnecessary/redundant, and should I just do this instead:

```
<article>

   <h1>Heading Title</h1>

   ...

</article>
```

Comment: That depends on what _meaning_ you want to have the content inside the `h1`, I’d say … if that content actually constitutes a header for the whole page, then there is nothing wrong with using `header`.

Comment: Perhaps the best argument against semantics is the fact nobody ever agrees on semantics.

Comment: You might be interested in the [W3C wiki `<header>` page](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/header) and the [W3C HTML5 `<header>` spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element), which explain the element's intention and some semantics/examples for it.

Comment: What do you expect to gain from using `header` in the first place?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I am hoping to gain a properly-formed, semantic HTML5 document.

Comment: @PeterAndrews, meaning what? How would a) the appearance b) the functionality differ?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Unless I am mistaken, there would be no difference in either appearance or functionality. What I am concerned about is whether it is more correct to do it one way or the other *from an HTML5 semantics point of view*.

Comment: So, it is a matter of opinion only, isn’t it? “HTML5 semantics” is just a collection of opinions (and does not relate to real semantics, i.e. meaning; `header` says nothing about the *meaning* of the content, just (at most) about its structural role in a site.

Comment: "So, it is a matter of opinion only, isn’t it?"  

It may be just a matter of opinion, but I can hardly image that there is no "best practice" or leading school of thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the first Note section on the W3C's `header` spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element) which [ajp15243](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883647/ajp15243) mentioned above, emphasis mine:

> A header element is intended to usually contain the section's heading (an h1–h6 element), but **this is not required**. The header element can also be used to wrap a section's table of contents, a search form, or any relevant logos.

If all you have is a single (as per your example) `<h1></h1>`, the `<header>` tag is not required for your document to be properly-formed and semantically correct.

You might find that having the `<header>` element as a wrapper aids you in styling the `h1` later with CSS, but as far as the HTML alone in this case, you're semantically fine either with or without `<header>`.

Comment: This does not address the question asked. It deals with the possible content of the element, not whether it should be used or not.

Comment: I understood that note to mean "the <header> element is not required as a wrapper for a section's h1-h6 element", but I see how it could also be interpreted as "you can use <header> without an h1-h6 inside".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it’s unnecessary in this specific case. Which means, you may use a `header` (it wouldn’t be wrong) but it’s also not required.

[`header`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/sections.html#the-header-element) (together with [`footer`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/sections.html#the-footer-element) and [`address`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/sections.html#the-address-element)) is used to markup a *section*’s content that is not considered to be the main content [*of that section*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22387534/1591669). A section can be a [sectioning root](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/sections.html#sectioning-root) (like `body`) or a [sectioning content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/dom.html#sectioning-content-0) (like `article`) element.

So when your header would contain more than a heading element (for example, [a subtitle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22451639/1591669)), you should use a `header` element, because otherwise it wouldn’t be clear if this content is part of the header or the main content. But in case of a single heading element, it’s clear by [definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/sections.html#headings-and-sections): the first heading element in a section is the heading for this section.