# Multiple Headers and ARIA Roles

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have an HTML Structure which really has 2 headers: At the tippity top of  the page it has some navigation items and buttons, below that is another section which holds the logo and what I would call the main navigation.

Both are sectioned off in wrappers because of full width CSS3 gradients so my structure looks something like this:

```
<div id="topWrap">
    <div id="topNavWrap">
        <nav id="utilityLinks"> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="quickLinks">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="headerWrap">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="logo.png" /></a></div>
        <nav id="mainNav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Main Service Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Main Service Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Main Service Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Main Service Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Main Service Page</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is:

1. In this situation is it acceptable to wrap both of these `nav` elements in a `header` element, do I just wrap my main `nav` and logo in a `header` element, or do I wrap both in one big `header` element?
2. When using Aria, should I use `role="main"` on my main navigation or my main `header` element?

Comment: 2) Neither, of course – you should use `role="main"` on what is it intended for – the main _content_ section of your document. Using it on the navigation doesn’t make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense to use `header` for both of these.

As `header` has no influence on the document outline, it’s up to you use one or several `header` elements; it doesn’t affect the meaning. If there is no reason not to use one element (i.e., there is no content inbetween that should not be part of `header`), go with one element.

The [ARIA role `main`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-wai-aria-20140320/roles#main) is for the main content of a page. Navigation is typically not the main content, unless it’s the only content and purpose of a page. However, in that case you wouldn’t use the `header` element, as its job is to ["exclude" content that is not considered to be part of the main content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25324129/1591669).

Answer (score 1):

If they are using `nav` elements you shouldn't simply wrap them in headers. Although you can use multiple header elements in a page, they should represent the top of a 'section', a content area.

A more suitable HTML setup would be:

```
<header id="topWrap" role="banner">
  <div id="topNavWrap">
      <nav id="utilityLinks" role="navigation" aria-describedby="utilityLinksH2"> 
          <h2 class="at" id="utilityLinksH2">Site menu</h2>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              ...
          </ul>
      </nav>
      <div id="quickLinks">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
              ...
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div id="headerWrap">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="logo.png" /></a></div>
      <nav id="mainNav" aria-describedby="mainNavH2">
         <h2 class="at" id="mainNavH2">Service menu</h2>
         <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Main Service Page</a></li>
              ...
         </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Notable points are:

- wrapping the whole lot in a `header`, with a role of `banner`. which should only be used once on a page to denote site furniture at the top of the page. (When used from the body the header applies to the, [see the last example in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-header-element).)
- Labelling each `nav` with a hidden sub-heading (use .at to move it offscreen), with `aria-describedby`.

Main should wrap the main content of the page (that is unique to the page), generally starting just above a H1. There should be only one.