# <header> to wrap logo, language switch and hamburger button?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

What wrapper should I use, `<header>`? I'm used to `<div>`, but I want a modern markup if reasonable. Based on the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-header-element) quote below, it seems like a good choice. Is it?

> The header element represents a group of introductory or navigational aids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `header` element for these parts.

[The spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-header-element) notes that it can be used for "any relevant logos" and the last examples shows that the `header` contains the navigation (which a language switcher and a hamburger button typically are).

You could also use [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25541916/1591669) `header` elements, e.g., if there’s something between these parts that should not be part of the `header`.